# What are the security risks for uploading directly to SQL server from Arduino without PHP server?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arduino, esp8266

Using the Arduino UNO and the ESP-8266, what are the security risks for connecting and uploading data directly from the Arduino? Instead of sending a POST request to a PHP web server with the data?

I know the PHP method is safer but I just want to know clearly what and how data is not safe that way.

Comment: Will you be connecting directly to SQL Server or MySQL? They're a bit different. Is the database server exposed to the entire Internet or accessible only on a local network (or via VPN)?

Comment: Have you looked at security.stackexchange.com? [This answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/181142/91314) might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think web server is safer than a client application. Though you have https, a lot of database servers supports TLS too for communication, which is also safe.

But you will need to enable the encrypt feature in database server. For mysql, I think it is default to use TLS encryption so it is safe.

The differences need to be considered are:

1. API

direct db access: need to install DB access client software (api)

web: standard  web access, no api installation required

2. DB exposure

direct db access: exposes db structure and authenticate. Something like user/password is stored locally on the pc and has risk of leaking.

web: only exposes limited information

3. server port exposure

Usually database port is only accessable in LAN. That means you can not use direct db access on WAN if the port is not open.

4. connection timespan

web access usually is state-less. That means one page a connection, and connection is closed as soon as page is loaded. direct db access will keep the db connection open throughout the application live period.

usually db connection count is limited. if client app is not well written it may use up all connectiions and make the database not accessible.

5. version control

web access: you only need to upgrade on the web server.

db access: you need to install new versions on each client pc.

6. performance

web access: slower than direct db access.

So if all your users are in a LAN and all pcs are trusted, I don't see a reason to introduce a web server.